# What is the right approach to encapsulate platform specific code in Go?

Tags: go, architecture, cross-platform

I want to develop a small Go application, which shows the used key stroke shortcuts to the audience of a presentation.

To hook into the keyboard events I will have to use some platform specific code. **What is the Go way to encapsulate platform specific code?** I've been searching for keywords like compiler switch or platform modules, but I couldn't really find something about.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you mean by "encapsulate"? Also, what's wrong with `runtime.GOOS`, with an if statement?

Comment: I used encapsulate, because I wanted to ask for the Go-way to separate platform specific code. Nothing is wrong with runtime.GOOS, if it can handle platform specific code, which probably doesn't compile on other platforms.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I'm not sure encapsulate is the correct word, but fair enough. To your second point, I honestly can't think of an example of valid Go code that will compile on one *platform* but not on another. (Different compilers are a different problem.) I can think of a few examples that might crash or break, however, but that's the idea of `if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {}`.

Comment: What would be a better word? I'm always up to learn something :-)

Comment: Well, to me, "encapsulate" has connotations of A) absurd OOP object models and design / API principles (Java#, anyone?) or B) hiding what's happening through source code obfuscation / more absurd API exposure principles. Better words might be "separate", or perhaps in this case "conditionally compile". :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution to platform specific code is the [build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints).

<sup>**Note:** Prior to Go 1.17 the syntax was a comment line starting with `// +build`, but Go 1.17 introduced the `//go:build` pragma which is now the preferred way.</sup>

> A build constraint, also known as a build tag, is a line comment that begins
>
> ```
> //go:build
> ```
>
> that lists the conditions under which a file should be included in the package. Constraints may appear in any kind of source file (not just Go), but they must appear near the top of the file, preceded only by blank lines and other line comments. These rules mean that in Go files a build constraint must appear before the package clause.

So basically each platform specific Go code should go into different files, and you can mark each of these Go files with the target they are intended for.

For example if a file contains Linux specific code (e.g. syscalls), start it with:

```
//go:build linux
```

If a file contains Windows specific syscalls, start it with:

```
//go:build windows
```

A lot more "options" are available, read the linked docs. For example you can specify constraints to the OS, Architecture, Go version, the compiler being used. You can also specify multiple constraints that will be interpreted with logical OR or AND, or you can use negation (e.g. this code is for every target platform except linux).

You can even mark a `.go` file to be ignored with the following constraint:

```
//go:build ignore
```

Note that build constraints are compiler specific. If a specific compiler does not recognize a build constraint, the compiler will ignore the file. As an example the Go AppEngine SDK comes with a built-in, modified Go compiler which additionally recognizes the

```
//go:build appengine
```

constraint, which means the source file is intended for the Google App Engine Platform only. "Regular" Go compilers will ignore the file, giving you the possibility to not have a bunch of compiler errors if someone tries to build the code without the Go AppEngine SDK.

Answer (score 7):

While [@icza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35429081/4532996) is definitely the proper authoritative answer to OP's question about condtional compilation, in this specific case a simpler approach may be worthwhile.

Go is a language designed to compile the same (with the same compiler) on every platform, to encourage cross-platform code and library reuse. Go is not C/C++, for which time must be spent to write explicitly cross-platform code.

Of course, the platform agnosticity only goes as far as Go's runtime, and you're trying to capture keypresses, for which there's no real single platform-agnostic solution.

Thus, my simpler suggestion *for this use case* resembles the following:

```
package main

import (
    "runtime"
    kp "kplib"
)

func main () {
    switch runtime.GOOS {
    case "windows":
        kp.WinKey()
    case "darwin":
        kp.MacKey()
    case "linux":
        kp.UnixKey()
    default:
        kp.TryKey()
    }
}
```

With the implicit assurance the hypothetical `kplib` will compile everywhere (just be sure to call the right methods on the given platform!).

Answer (score 1):

To make code platform-specific, you can go for `build constraints`. [For more info](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/customizing-go-binaries-with-build-tags)

**Windows**

```
//go:build windows
// +build windows
```

**Not Windows**

```
//go:build !windows
// +build !windows
```

**Not Windows & Darwin**

```
//go:build !windows && !darwin
// +build !windows,!darwin
```

**Mac**

```
//go:build darwin
// +build darwin
```

**Linux**

```
//go:build linux
// +build linux
```

**Example**

```golang
//go:build windows
// +build windows

package main

func main() {
   // windows specific code
}
```

Or you can place the code in separate file for different OS with `file naming convention`.

Eg:-

path

- path.go
- path_windows.go
- path_darwin.go
- path_linux.go

[Building go applications for different OS & Architecture](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/building-go-applications-for-different-operating-systems-and-architectures)